# Volver a pedir datos si no se cumple condición en bucle do-while

Tags: c#

Tengo la siguiente función que pide tres datos sobre partidos (ganados, empatados y perdidos) dentro una serie de bucles `do-while` para asegurarme que sólo se avance cuando no sean negativos.

Al final, si el total de partidos es superior a 20, ¿cómo hago que le programa me vuelva a pedir los datos iniciales? ¿Cómo se puede volver a pedir los datos en C# si la condición no se cumple con `do-while`?

```
static void CalculoMatricula()
{
    int p_ganados, p_empatados, p_perdidos, ganados, empatados, perdidos, total_partidos, total_puntos;
    //do
    // {
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Ingrese los partido ganados: "); // el numero ingresado no puede ser negativo
        p_ganados = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    while (p_ganados < 0);
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Ingrese los partidos empatados: "); // el numero ingresado no puede ser negativo
        p_empatados = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    while (p_empatados < 0);
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Ingrese los partidos perdidos: "); // el numero ingresado no puede ser negativo
        p_perdidos = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    while (p_perdidos < 0);
    ganados = 3 * 1;
    empatados = 1 * 1;
    perdidos = -1 * 1;
    total_puntos = (p_ganados * ganados) + (p_empatados * empatados) + (p_perdidos * perdidos); //total puntos ganados
    // do
    //{
    total_partidos = p_ganados + p_empatados + p_perdidos; // partidos jugados total
    //} while (total_partidos > 20);
    // si el total de partidos ganados es superior a 20
    // como hago que le programa me vuelva a pedir los datos iniciales
    //}
    // while (total_partidos < 0);
    Console.WriteLine("El total de los partidos jugados es: " + total_partidos);
    Console.WriteLine("El puntaje total de los partidos jugados es: " + total_puntos);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Las preguntas que son solo codigo tienden a no ser bien vistas, ya que no sabemos exactamente que problema tienes o que hace tu codigo.

Comment: Hola @Fenix09, he editado la pregunta para añadir una breve descripción basada en el título y los comentarios del código. Las preguntas que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad porque sin un enunciado claro, son difíciles de entender y son menos útiles para la comunidad. Lee [ask] para más información. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Mirando tu código, lo tenías casi hecho y lo habías comentado. Tenías la idea correcta pero la aplicaste en el `do-while` equivocado. Tienes comentados estos dos bucles `do-while`:

- Uno interno que comprueba que el número de partidos no sea mayor que 20.
- Uno global (que lo envuelve todo) que comprueba que el número de partidos sea positivo.

Sin entrar a especular sobre cuándo comentaste o no uno, la solución obvia sería mover la comprobación de ese bucle interno al bucle global (puedes seguir manteniendo los `do-while` que comprueban que los números sean positivos). De ese modo si el número total de partidos introducido es mayor que 20, la función se volverá a repetir.

Aquí puedes ver el código modificado. Si te fijas, es el mismo código que tenías, sólo quitando el comentario del `do-while` global y moviendo la comprobación del `do-while` interno al global. Lo dicho, lo tenías casi hecho.

El código con esos cambios ([lo puedes ver funcionando en este .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9uPEqI)):

```
static void CalculoMatricula()
{
    int p_ganados, p_empatados, p_perdidos, ganados, empatados, perdidos, total_partidos, total_puntos;
    do
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Ingrese los partido ganados: "); // el numero ingresado no puede ser negativo
            p_ganados = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        while (p_ganados < 0);
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Ingrese los partidos empatados: "); // el numero ingresado no puede ser negativo
            p_empatados = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        while (p_empatados < 0);
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Ingrese los partidos perdidos: "); // el numero ingresado no puede ser negativo
            p_perdidos = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        while (p_perdidos < 0);

        ganados = 3 * 1;
        empatados = 1 * 1;
        perdidos = -1 * 1;
        total_puntos = (p_ganados * ganados) + (p_empatados * empatados) + (p_perdidos * perdidos); //total puntos ganados
        // do
        //{
        total_partidos = p_ganados + p_empatados + p_perdidos; // partidos jugados total
        //} while (total_partidos > 20);
        // si el total de partidos ganados es superior a 20
        // como hago que le programa me vuelva a pedir los datos iniciales
    }
    while (total_partidos > 20);
    Console.WriteLine("El total de los partidos jugados es: " + total_partidos);
    Console.WriteLine("El puntaje total de los partidos jugados es: " + total_puntos);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Si no te molesta la idea de que vuelva a pedir todos los datos si algún dato ingresado es negativo, podrías hacerlo todo con un solo do while de la siguiente forma

```
   do{
        Console.Write("Ingrese los partido ganados: ");// el numero ingresado
                                                       // no puede ser negativo
        p_ganados = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Ingrese los partidos empatados: ");// el numero ingresado 
                                                          // no puede ser negativo
        p_empatados = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Ingrese los partidos perdidos: ");// el numero ingresado 
                                                         // no puede ser negativo
        p_perdidos = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

       }while(p_ganados < 0 || p_empatados < 0 || p_perdidos < 0);
```

Aqui lo que hacemos es preguntar por los resultados, si algún resultado es negativo vuelve a preguntar de nuevo los resultados hasta que ninguno sea negativo.

Answer (score -2):

```
static void CalculoMatricula()
{
    int p_ganados, p_empatados, p_perdidos, ganados, empatados, perdidos, total_partidos, total_puntos;
    //do
    // {

    SolicitarPartidosGanados: //ETIQUETA QUE ENVIA 
    Console.Write("Ingrese los partido ganados: ");// el numero ingresado no puede ser negativo         
    if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out p_ganados)) //Si el usuario no teclea un valor entero manda a  la condición
    {
        goto SolicitarPartidosGanados; // Si se cumple la condición en la que el usuario no tecleo un valor entero, entonces manda a la etiqueta SolicitarPuntosGanados
    }

    SolicitarPartidosEmpatados:
    Console.Write("Ingrese los partidos empatados: ");// el numero ingresado no puede ser negativo
    if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out p_empatados))
    {
        goto SolicitarPartidosEmpatados;
    }

    SolicitarPartidosPerdidos:
    Console.Write("Ingrese los partidos perdidos: ");
    if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out p_perdidos))
    {
        goto SolicitarPartidosPerdidos;
    } 

    ganados = 3 * 1;
    empatados = 1 * 1;
    perdidos = -1 * 1;


    total_puntos = (p_ganados * ganados) + (p_empatados * empatados) + (p_perdidos * perdidos);//total puntos ganados

    // do
    //{
    total_partidos = p_ganados + p_empatados + p_perdidos;// partidos jugados total
                                                          //} while (total_partidos > 20);
                                                          // si el total de partidos ganados es superior a 20
                                                          // como hago que le programa me vuelva a pedir los datos iniciales



    //}
    // while (total_partidos < 0);
    Console.WriteLine("El total de los partidos jugados es: " + total_partidos);
    Console.WriteLine("El puntaje total de los partidos jugados es: " + total_puntos);

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: Por favor no agregues varias respuestas, te sugiero agregar una que ayude a solucionar o de alguna opción  a el problema que plantea en usuario, revisa por favor [answer], saludos!.

Answer (score -3):

Podrías probar con esto:

```
string var = Console.ReadLine();
p_ganados = Convert.ToInt32(var);
```

No sé bien cuál de los bucles te está fallando, pero fíjate si cambiando la forma en que conviertes a entero te sirve.